# Query mysql, place empty fields, and export data as CSV using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

What would be the best approach to create a CSV file that contains 100+ fields where only 1/3 is actually being used?

A simple example is (bear with me):

If I have a 5 column table (X,O,#,T,P) with X amount of rows and the csv format needs to be

```
X,,,,O,,,,T,P,,,,,,#,,,
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can either select the fields you want or select * and output to a csv file.

Comment: @user2260040 His question is how to create all the empty fields in between the columns he's selecting.

Comment: i need all the fields. I am looking for the best/right way to do it where the empty fields are inserted as well.

Comment: @tai check my answer using modified `select` query iteself

Answer (score 0):

you can export table data to csv file directly using mysql query

```
"SELECT column1, column2, column3 INTO OUTFILE '<filename>' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM table1;"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is you can place dummy columns in `select` query itself and then just create a `CSV` from the output:

```
select X,'','','',O,'','','',T,P,'','','','','',#,'','' from table_name; // this will by default give you your CSV structured output.

$fp = fopen('file_name', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create lots of empty fields in the `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT X, '' AS col2, '' AS col3, '', O, '', '', '', '', T, P, '', '', '', '', '', '', `#`, '', ''
INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM yourTable;
```

When reading the file back into the table, you can specify which fields of the file go into the table like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv'
INTO TABLE yourTable
(X, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, O, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, T, P, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, `#`, @dummy, @dummy);
```

The `@dummy` variables receive the values of those file fields, while the column names receive those file fields.

Comment: if i use a select query how would i enter in header information?

Comment: Use column aliases. I updated my answer to show the aliases for the first few columns, I didn't bother repeating it throughout.